# Задача Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi

```
program Project4_3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
var
  a:array [1..3, 1..4] of real;
  b:array [1..3] of real;
  i,j:integer;
  s,sred:real;
begin
  for i:=1 to 3 do begin
    s:=0;
    for j:=1 to 4 do begin
      readln (a[i,j]);
      s:=s+a[i,j];
      writeln(s);
    end;
  end;
  begin
  for i:=1 to 3 do begin
  sred:=0;
  for j:=1 to 4 do begin
  readln (a[i,j]);
  sred := sred+a[i,j];
  sred := sred/3;
  writeln(sred);
  end;
  end;
  end;
  end.
```

Вывод в одной строке с двумя знаками после десятичной точки 
   значений первых элементов этих двух одномерных массивов, 
   затем вывод во второй строке также с двумя знаками после десятичной точки 
   значений вторых элементов этих двух одномерных массивов, 
   затем вывод в третьей строке также с двумя знаками после десятичной точки 
   значений третьих элементов этих двух одномерных массивов.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно "вывод в одной строке с двумя знаками после десятичной точки значений" делается так (если число перед точкой  тоже останется) :

```
  writeln(s:4:2);
```

Вывод элементов массива (сперва первых эл, потом вторых, и т.д.) можно сделать таким образом:

```
for i:=0 to length(a) do
  for j:=0 to 1 do
  begin 
    writeln(a[j]);
    writelb(b[j]);
  end;
```

Но один нюанс: массивы должны быть одной длинны. Плюс вы говорите о одномерных массивах, а в коде присутствует двумерный (а) массив.